# Consider the sequence $a_1 = 24^{1/3}$ $a_{n+1} = (a_n + 24)^{1/3},n ≥ 1.$ Then what is the integer part of $a_{100}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, recursion

**QUESTION:** Consider the sequence

$a_1 = 24^{1/3}$
$a_{n+1} = (a_n + 24)^{1/3},n ≥ 1.$

Then what is the integer part of $a_{100}$ ?

**MY APPROACH:** I tried this one really hard but couldn't get the trick.. I used log, but that doesn't really help and the problem becomes more and more complex, so I am avoiding a confusing solution here..

Then I tried by defining a function say $$f(x)=(x+24)^\frac{1}3$$ Therefore by computing the derivative of $f$ we find that the *rate at which the function increases, decreases with increase in x*. Which also is quite clear from intuition. But I could not apply the result to solve the problem.

Can we form a recursive series for it? Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you show the sequence is increasing, and its elements are between $2$ and $3$?

Comment: It looks like this sequence converges.  Maybe you can show what it converges toward.

Comment: @J. W. Tanner  , I get that the sequence is increasing but how do I prove that the elements are between $2$ and $3$ ?

Comment: If it's increasing and starts with $24^{1/3}$, it has to stay more than $2=8^{1/3}$, and if a term is less than $3$ then the subsequent term is less than $(3+24)^{1/3}=3$

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much @J. W. Tanner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove by induction that $2 < a_n < 3$ for all $n$.

Comment: You can also prove that the sequence is increasing and converges to $3$, but that is irrelevant for the question.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint.. I tend to forget sometimes that there is a method called induction, when nothing can be done .. so the answer to this question is $2$ right?

Comment: @StrangerForever, yes, exactly

Comment: I don't know how to prove that..... Although it's irrelevant (the induction is much easier), will you tell me how to do that?  learning never hurts :)

Comment: @StrangerForever, prove by induction that the sequence is increasing. Use the monotone sequence theorem to prove that it converges: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers .Find its limit.

Comment: Thank you.. I will surely check it out!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108957/discussion-between-stranger-forever-and-lhf).

Answer (score 2):

If $x<3$, then $f(x)<(3+24)^{1/3}=3$. 
If $x\geq 0$, then $f(x)\geq(0+24)^{1/3}>2$.

So what can you say about $a_{100}=f^{100}(0)$?

Comment: By $f^{100}(0)$ do you mean the $100^{th}$ derivetive of $f$ ?

Comment: @Stranger Forever, no. $f^{100}$ is apply $f$ 100 times, i.e.$f^{100}(0)= f(f(...f(0)...))$. That is what you want since $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$.

Comment: Yeah, it will be less than $3$.. I get it..

Answer (score 1):

given , $a_1= 24^{1/3}$

$\implies  $$a_1 <3$   as $27^{1/3}$ is 3

$a_{n+1}=(a_n+24)^{1/3} $

$a_2 = (a_1+24)^{1/3}$

since $a_1<3 $

$\implies $$(a_1+24)^{1/3}$ <3

$\implies $$a_2<3$

similary $a_3<3$, $a_4<3$ and so on

$\Rightarrow$ $a_n<3$ $\Rightarrow$ $a_{100}$<3 ----1

Now, for any value of $a_n$(+ve,<3) in $a_{n+1}=(a_n+24)^{1/3}$ the expression is always greater than 2

$\Rightarrow$ 2<$a_n$<3

$\Rightarrow$ 2<$a_{100}$<3

Therefore , the integral part of $a_{100}$ is 2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The two 3 years ago answers were sufficient.